# What's the Cost Threshold for Parallelism value I should set for this SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, configuration

Here is the output from Brent Ozar's EXEC [dbo].[sp_BlitzFirst] @SinceStartup = 1;
Thank Brent, It gives me the whole picture of the WATIS on this box.

But my question is what's the number of the cost threshold for parallelism should I set instead of the default 5?

So I read through Jonathan's https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/tuning-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-from-the-plan-cache/

But I cannot get the results by that query and my SQL Server is SQL 2016 SP2-CU12.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: There's no magic number. Adjust, observe, repeat. Start at 50, see how that does. Are you solving an actual problem, or are you just attacking the highest waits? Waits are a normal part of a functioning system, and there will always be a highest wait. You will always have a worst employee, but you can't fire every worst employee successively.

Comment: There is no magic number; it depends on you workload.

Comment: Thank you guys, I know it's a leverage game. Through Jonathan's document, it looks there is a way to calculate the cached plan's subtreecost. Maybe it's a way to give us a number to do our first guess of that value...

Comment: Perhaps there are no cached parallel plans, hence no results returned by the query. Consider the aggregated wait stats will include activity like parallel index rebuilds that aren't reflected in the plan cache and also skew results. Not saying you shouldn't tweak the threshold, just that you shouldn't try to solve a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed. There is no magic number. It depends on the workload and/or problem you're trying to solve.

A CTFP of 5 is too low for nearly all cases.

50 is a good starting point, and adjust up or down from there.

Parallelism by itself is not an issue. It can be a good thing for trawling through huge datasets. If no one's complaining, though, why bother fixing it?

If, however, you know queries or procs are going parallel when they definitely shouldn't be, these wait times might point to a problem.

If you're a fan of Brent Ozar, try running `sp_BlitzCache` with `@SortOrder = 'reads'` or `@SortOrder = 'cpu'`.

That should return the worst performing queries, in terms of page reads or cpu time. I find the Warnings and Query Plan columns a good launch pad for further investigation.